# Capistrano error: no servers found to match {:once=>true, :eof=>true}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rbenv

Just updated my gems and no I get the following error when I try to run any `cap` command.

```
no servers found to match {:once=>true, :eof=>true}
```

My gem versions are:

```
capistrano (2.15.5)
capistrano-platform-resources (0.1.3)
capistrano-rbenv (1.0.5)
```

And my config/deploy.rb looks something like:

```
# the name of the application
set :application, "appname"

# RVM
require "capistrano-rbenv"
set :rbenv_ruby_version, "1.9.3-p194"

# Bundler
require "bundler/capistrano"

# General

# this should be the username on the server
set :user, "deploy"

# the path to install the application in on the server
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/path/to/#{application}"
# Setting this to 'remote_cache' will ensure that only
# changes are sent to the server, not the whole repository
# NOTE: Can only use remote_cache in conjunction with github repos
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :use_sudo, false

# Git

# Github say I need this, thus I need it
# INFO: http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/
default_run_options[:pty] = true

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:dtuite/#{application}.git"
# the local location of the app.
# which branch to checkout during deploy
set :branch, "master"

# the IP address of the VPS
server  "[the server ip]", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting

```
# the IP address of the VPS
server  "[the server ip]", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
```

And declare the domain seperately, like so -

```
# App Domain
    set :domain, "yourdomain.com or IP address"
```

And then this to replace the line you deleted -

```
    # All components of the app on the same server
 server domain, :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
```

Comment: Some combination of this answer and moving the server declaration closer to the top of `config/deploy.rb` seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks.